# undefined method `keys' for nil:NilClass in tic tac toe game RUBY

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to build a simple 2 player tic tac toe game in Ruby.
Here is the code:

```
class Morpion

   def init
      create_grid
      get_player
      show_grid
   end
   def get_player
      puts "Let play some Tic Tac Toe"
      puts ""
      @player1 ='X'
      @player2='O'
          puts ""
          puts "Where would you like to move? (check out the grid below and type any number 1-9 to place your symbol): "
          puts " 1 | 2 | 3 "
          puts "---+---+---"
          puts " 4 | 5 | 6 "
          puts "---+---+---"
          puts " 7 | 8 | 9 "
   end

   def create_grid
        @grid = {
            '1' => ' ',
            '2' => ' ',
            '3' => ' ',
            '4' => ' ',
            '5' => ' ',
            '6' => ' ',
            '7' => ' ',
            '8' => ' ',
            '9' => ' '
        }
   end

    def show_grid
        puts ""
        puts "#{@grid['1']}|#{@grid['2']}|#{@grid['3']}"
        puts "-----"
        puts "#{@grid['4']}|#{@grid['5']}|#{@grid['6']}"
        puts "-----"
        puts "#{@grid['7']}|#{@grid['8']}|#{@grid['9']}"
        puts ""
    end

   def play
       number_turns=1
       while number_turns < 10
        number_turns.odd? ? player_turn(@player1) : player_turn(@player2)
        game_checker
        if game_checker
          break
        end
        number_turns+=1
       end  
   end

   def player_turn(player)
        puts player == 'X' ? "It's X's turn!" : "It's O's turn!"
        puts ""
        cell = gets.chomp
        unless @grid.keys.include?(cell) #check if the user entered a number corresponding to the grid
            puts ""
            puts "it has to be a number from 1 to 9"
            player_turn(player)
        end
        if @grid[cell] == ' ' #check if cell in grid is empty for user input
            @grid[cell] = player
        else
            puts ""
            puts "That cell is occupied. Choose again!"
            player_turn(player)
        end
        show_grid
   end

   def game_checker
        end_game = false
      if @grid['1'] != ' ' && @grid['5'] != ' ' && @grid['9'] != ' '
        if (@grid['1'] == @grid['2'] && @grid['1'] == @grid['3'])
            end_game = true
            victory = @grid['1']
          elsif (@grid['4'] == @grid['5'] && @grid['4'] ==@grid['6'])
            end_game = true
            victory = @grid['4']
          elsif (@grid['7'] == @grid['8'] && @grid['7'] == @grid['9'])
            end_game = true
            victory = @grid['7']
          elsif (@grid['1'] == @grid['4'] && @grid['1'] == @grid['7'])
            end_game = true
            victory = @grid['1']
          elsif (@grid['2'] == @grid['5'] && @grid['2'] == @grid['8'])
            end_game= true
            victory = @grid['2']
          elsif (@grid['3'] == @grid['6'] && @grid['3'] == @grid['9'])
            end_game = true
            victory = @grid['3']
          elsif (@grid['1'] == @grid['5'] && @grid['1'] == @grid['9'])
            end_game = true
            victory = @grid['1']
          elsif (@grid['3'] == @grid['5'] && @grid['3'] == @grid['7'])
            end_game = true
            victory = @grid['3']
          else
            end_game = false
        end
      end
        if end_game 
           puts "the winner of this game is #{victory}"
           return true
        end
   end


end


m=Morpion.new
m.play
```

So my issue is this: 
1. I am asking a player to add his symbol (X or O) in the grid that ranges from 1 to 9 (because there is 9 cells)

2. if I enter 1 for example, which is the upper left cell I get this error:

   `` (eval):187: undefined method `keys' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) ``
   `` from (eval):168:in `play' ``
   `from (eval):245`

If you want to run this program I suggest using [THIS LINK](http://repl.it/languages/Ruby)

EDIT:
The problem as [@Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/877472/paul-richter) and [@August](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2498956/august) stated was that I used an incorrect constructor method `init` instead of using the correct one: `initialize`.
Now my program works. Thanks to them.

Comment: So its crapping out on this line? `unless @grid.keys.include?(space)`

Comment: exactly and I can't figure out why because the key values of my `@grid` hash goes from 1 to 9, so entering "1" or "3" or whatever should work...or not. I don't know at this point.

Comment: Why are you storing the grid in a hash? You're not using it as a hash. All you need are nine values--an array would be fine. Your input validation should simply be checking for a digit, e.g. `if space !~ /^\d$/` or `unless ('1'..'9').include? space`

Comment: Once you get it working, you may want to post this on codereview.stackexchange.com. You'll get some helpful hints.

Comment: Good idea Mark, so all I need to change is the hash to a 2D array and then use `unless ('1'..'9').include? space` to check for input?

Comment: Yes, however a 1D array is all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `@grid` variable is never being created; it is `nil`. Hence the error message, you're attempting to invoke a method on a `nil` object.

The cause of your woes is because you've misnamed the constructor method. In Ruby, constructors are named `initialize`, however you named it `init`. Rename it to the correct name, and it should work.

Comment: dude... Sometimes the answer is just straight in front of me and I can't see it. Thank you for the correction Paul.

Comment: @Cyzanfar I know the feeling. Mark Thomas makes a good point in the question-comments. You might do better to use something like a 2-dimensional array (like x and y values on a graph). A flat array would work fine as well.

Comment: I see... something like this: `@grid = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`

Comment: @Cyzanfar Yup, that's correct. Whenever I do stuff like this, I find it helpful to think in terms of graphs; so in this case, your Y value would be the outer array, and the X would be the inner array of that row. Ex: To get the value 4 in your example, would be `Y = 1` and `X = 0` (zero-based indexes of course).

Comment: @Cyzanfar And as mark pointed out, a 1d array would work fine too. You can make the choice.

Answer (score 2):

You initialize the `@grid` hash in a method called `init`. Ruby won't call this method when you construct a new instance of `Game`. You should instead rename the `init` method to `initialize`, which will be called automatically by Ruby.